# Сделать rtf из txt при помощи php и расставить в нем разрывы страниц

Tags: php, ms-word, rtf

Ребят, может кто-то сталкивался с подобным. Я парсю txt-файлы, там встречаются дни недели, и мне нужно перед каждым днем недели (кроме понедельника) вставить разрыв страницы и сохранить файлы в rtf. Как обозначить этот самый разрыв? Все знают "`\n`" и т.п, а как быть с более специфическими знаками?
Спасибо!

Comment: нужно шрифту выставить кодировку 1251, и передавать симвоы `\'XX` где ХХ - шеснадцатиричный код символа.

Comment: Ок, допустим файл изначально в win1251. Как в нем произвести замену? `preg_replace('/вторник|среда|четверг|пятница|суббота|воскресенье/i', "день\XX", $file)`?

Comment: Разрыв страницы в ASCII кодировке это 0х0С или chr(12)

Comment: В rtf разрыв страницы `\pard;` (перенос на новый лист) а перенос сроки (абзац) `\par;` (первый комент вытру)

Comment: Покажите конкретный символ с которым у вас проблема - покажу как перевести. На управляющие в rtf свои коды, остальные кодируются через `\'ХХ`. Так же, можно набрать в rtf текст, и между допустим -------- посмотреть что за комбинация символов там.

Comment: Я немного запутался в последовательности действий. Сначала `$file = file_get_contents('file.txt')`, потом `$file = preg_replace('--тут дни недели--', "\12", $file)`. Затем `file_put_contents('file.RTF', $file)`, верно?

Comment: Или СНАЧАЛА сделать rtf, а потом производить замену в нем?

Comment: Я не могу дать вам ответ на php. Ответ какой. Пишем шапку (голову) rtf `{\\rft1\\ansi\\ansicpg1251\\deff0\\deflang1049{` потом пишем текст, с реплейсом символов на те, которые понимает rtf ( т.е. убираем \ { } на экранированые, \n-> \\par; перевод-страницы -> \\pard; а русские символы лучше в `\'ХХ `преобразовать. ). Потом пишем хвост `}}`. Всё. Двойной слеш я использую, т.к. с++ и по-моему php тоже требуют удвоение слеша, что б он вывелся как слеш.

Comment: Это что получается, сначала надо все символы в ASCII, а только потом с ними работать?

Comment: Заголовок я ошибся `\\rtf1` вместо `\\rft1` Русский текст нужно перевести в 16-ричную систему. Т.е. "я" = 0xFF => `\'FF`. Но можно оставить без изменений (не переводить). Старые версии редакторов не понимают руссекий текст напрямую (требуют перевести), современные виндовые редакторы нормально показывают. С линуксом - не сталкивался. Если задача касается "выложить в мир" - я бы перекодировал бы. Если "для пользования небольшим кругом лиц"  - оставил бы как есть. Возможно кто-то с сообщества подскажет нужно ли перекодировать. Винда - почему-то делает перекодирование.

Comment: Ссылки http://www.codenet.ru/progr/formt/rtf1.php,   спецификация http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7105

Comment: Как не переводить, если просто открываю rtf блокнотом, а там кодированная белиберда. Хотя это, видимо, от того, что txt-файл изначально в win-1251. Вообще это для "узкого круга": необходимо rtf экспортировать в другие программы

Comment: А что если так? `$file = file_get_contents('file.txt'); $file = iconv('windows-1251', 'UTF-8', '$file); file_put_contents('1.rtf', $file);` Кодированных символов нет. И теперь нельзя просто использовать preg_replace?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77301/discussion-between-forever-young-and-nick-n-a).

Comment: Не нужно в utf-8. Надо шапка + win1251 + хвост.

Comment: Ну, вы же сами написали, что если для узкого круга, то можно и не перекодировать. Или я неправильно понял Вас?

Comment: Перекодировать в вид `я`=> `\'FF`  `ю`=`\'FE`, iconv это не делает. Я делал цикл с replace-ами. Т.е. цикл где буква заменяется на \' + код буквы в hex.